# Dual/Dutch American Citizen visiting Netherlands

Tags: usa, dual-nationality, netherlands, taxes

My wife and I live in the United States, I'm a dual American/Dutch citizen who has never lived in the Netherlands, my wife is American. We plan to move to travel in Europe, living in several EU countries for no longer than three months. We do not want to trigger a requirement to file both American and Dutch taxes. It might help to add, we do not have any European investments or European income and will not work in Europe, and our bank will remain in the United States. Our only reason to visit is to sightsee as a tourist. Does anyone have experience with this scenario? Thank you for any help. Peter

Comment: For tax questions, [Money.SE](https://money.stackexchange.com/) may be better. Most tax residency determinations are fairly complex and not a simple function of the length of stay.

Comment: Thanks for that advice, I'll check that out. Peter

Comment: Your wife will not be able to stay in the Netherlands for more than 3 months without a residence permit.  For her to get that permit,  you have to have an income of over €1684.80 (the amount may change next month), though there are some exceptions for which you may qualify.  Details are available at https://ind.nl/en/family/residence-permit-for-your-partner/preparing/conditions/Pages/conditions-start.aspx by choosing "American (USA)" and "Dutch."  You would have a much easier time in any other EU or EFTA country, assuming you have sufficient resources.

Comment: You might want to consider if the ‘sufficient ties test’ component is applicable to you for determining UK tax residence status https://www.expertsforexpats.com/expat-tax/statutory-residence-test/

Comment: Traveller, thank you so much for your comment, I'm sorry my post wasn't clear.  I'll fix that issue. As an American, I can visit the UK for up to 6 months without a visa, but it's actually the Netherlands I'm concerned about.  How long and under what circumstances can I live in the Netherlands( as a dual American Dutch citizen), or any EU country for that matter without triggering the Dutch government to consider me a tax-paying resident?

Comment: Thank you Phoog for your comment, We do have enough American income to pass the test, without having employment in the Netherlands. My real concern is how long can I live in any EU country without the Netherlands tax authority classifying me as a permanent resident of the Netherlands and requiring me to submit taxes records?

Comment: I understand that the question is about taxation, which is why I added a comment rather than an answer. I just to make sure that you understand that your wife has to get a residence permit in order to stay longer than 90 days, because the generous provisions of EU free-movement law do not apply to her in the Netherlands (whereas they do in the rest of the EU and the Schengen area). The requirements of Dutch law are rather more burdensome, including in most cases taking an "integration" course, but I suppose if you're just going to be there for a few months it should be possible to avoid that.

Comment: Another question is whether your wife's residence permit would make her a tax resident even if she doesn't spend more than 4 or 5 months in the country.  In other words, it might be simpler just to plan to spend 12 weeks there.  Or, if you're not set on being in the Netherlands, to go to any other European Union or Schengen country, where the administrative burden would be much less.

Comment: I think this is the answer: a tax resident in NL has a permanent residence in the Netherlands.  - your partner and/or family lives in the Netherlands; - you work in the Netherlands; - you have insurance in the NL; - your physician is resident in the NL; - you are a member of societies; - your kids receive an education in NL.

 I have no NL sources. I would be a non tax resident. only subject to tax of income from NL sources.
If you live in another EU country you can still be considered a Qualifying non-resident taxpayer but again, with no Dutch income, no tax burden as far as I can tell.